# Remove cache automatically from chrome when match page url

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to remove the cache when the user go to this url ***stackoverflow.com/?clear*** then reload and go to ***stackoverflow.com*** with a clean cache, I tried a many methods but I failed.

Here is my last attempt, It's not affect the cache at all!

**Manifest Code**

```
{
  "name": "stackoverflow",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.js","background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "page_action" :
  {
    "default_icon" : "icon.png",
    "default_title" : "Remove"
  },
  "permissions" : [
    "declarativeContent", "browsingData", "tabs"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  // Replace all rules ...
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    // With a new rule ...
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        // That fires when a page's URL contains a 'stackoverflow.com/?clea' ...
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { urlContains: 'stackoverflow.com/?clear' },
          })
        ],
        // And shows the extension's page action.
        actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
      }
    ]);
  });
});

function clearMe(tab) {
    var ms = (30 * 60) * 1000; // 30 minutes
    var time = Date.now() - ms;
    chrome.browsingData.removeCache({"since": time}, function() {
        chrome.tabs.update({url: 'http://stackoverflow.com'});
    });
}
//It will be perfect if user do not have to click
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(clearMe)
```

**I need better alternative to remove cache without even the user click a button.**

Comment: I do not think you can clear browser cache from javascript. It is a user driven event

Comment: @jsHero I'm using Chrome API 'chrome.browsingData.removeCache' [READ MORE](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData#method-removeCache)

Comment: @jsHero Magic words "Chrome API"

Comment: You could look into `chrome.tabs.update` with `bypassCache: true`

Comment: I get this error in console "Error in response to browsingData.removeCache: ReferenceError: bypassCache is not defined",,,,, It need more permissions?

Comment: @Jim You're using it wrong, it seems. Docs here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-reload But note that it does not wipe the cache, only forces that particular page load to bypass it.

Comment: Can you describe, why you want to clear the cache? Maybe there is a better alternative if you give more details about the usecase.

Comment: @GerdK I will use it on a website require new session to get the new update, some time they want the user to remove the cache or restart  the browser, I used clear cache on chrome extension and it works perfectly without restarting the browser. I need to work this updated without I have to click on the page action icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tabs` api should be enough for this. Here's how you should do it. I've tested it and it's working fine.

**Manifest Code**

```
{
  "name": "stackoverflow",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions" : [
    "tabs", "browsingData"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  // if url is changed
  if (changeInfo.url) {
    var url = changeInfo.url;

    if (url.indexOf("stackoverflow.com/?clear") != -1) {
      alert("Clearing cache...");
      clearMe(tab);
    }
  }
});

function clearMe(tab) {
  var ms = (30 * 60) * 1000; // 30 minutes
  var time = Date.now() - ms;
  chrome.browsingData.removeCache({"since": time}, function() {
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { url: 'http://stackoverflow.com' });
  });
}
```